# How can I use Natural Language Processing to check if a paragraph contains predefined topics?

Tags: nlp

We have a system that allows users to answer a question as free text and we want to check whether their answer contains any of our predefined topics. These topics will be defined prior to answers being submitted.

We tried to use a method similar to spam detection, but this is only good for determining whether something is true/false, incorrect/correct. We need the response to say which of the predefined topics a piece of text contains. Is there an algorithm that would solve this problem?

Comment: This is decidedly too broad.  What sort of topics are you looking for, and do you have an idea of how to establish their presence?  Naive approaches would tend to tag "I could kill for a drink" as "aggressive" but not necessarily "alcohol" (because "drink" has a neutral meaning, too -- potable liquid).

Comment: Also, summarically dismissing all possible spam filters seems premature.  There is a plethora of different techniques, many of which will probably compete favorably with whatever you end up selecting.

Comment: Questions would be similar to "Why should I do X when Y is fine?" and then we would want to make sure the response text contains our predefined answers such as "X doesn't do this bad thing, but Y does" or "90% of people that did X preferred it to Y".

Comment: You should still give us a rough idea of what X and Y stand for.  If they are very general or ambiguous, this is hard; if they are extremely well-defined and specific, just checking for their existence is probably enough, and you don't really need proper NLP beyond perhaps lemmatization or some other simple normalization step.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know potential X and Y so I'm as much in the dark as you :) We're looking into a proof of concept and the questions haven't been written yet. I think you're right that I don't need proper NLP though. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will try to use "bag of words" for feature extraction and "naive Bayes classifier with multinomial model" for classification.

In this page this described more detail [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

Comment: I guess this is what they meant by "a method similar to spam detection", though (possibly minus the "multinomial").

Comment: The spam detection method I used was at the bottom of this page http://php-nlp-tools.com/documentation/. I defined examples of spam/ham and then future "emails" would be classified based on the training examples.

Comment: That's binomial, but the method extends excellently to multinomial, i.e. any number of categories you care to define (plus probably one or more "spillover" category for training with samples which do not belong in any of your categories).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try explicit semantic analysis (ESA)`[1][2]`. Given a set of documents that represent concepts (in your case your topics) you can train a model and given any new sentence as input you can get a ranked list of the closest concepts "evoked" by that sentence. Of course this assume you have a document with some text describing every concept you want to identify (that's why the most common thing to do is to use Wikipedia pages as concepts), but if this is the case you could give it a try.

```
[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_semantic_analysis
[2] http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabr/papers/ijcai-2007-sim.pdf
```